# Dynamically extract pattern unique to each string in a list of strings in bash

Tags: bash, perl, awk, pattern-matching

I am trying to dynamically extract unique patterns from a list of filenames in bash.

Input list of filenames looks like this

`Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep2.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep3.txt`

I want to dynamically extract the strings

`Rep1,Rep2,Rep3`

Shown diagrammatically here:

[image: Example1]

NOTE: The input pattern can change every time
e.g. another use case may be

`Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_1_User1.png,Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_2_User1.png,Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_3_User1.png`

In this case, I want to extract

`1,2,3`

Shown diagrammatically here:

[image: Example2]

What is the best way to achieve this in bash?

---

As recommended in the comments, I tried the following:

`declare -p string1 string2`

```
declare -- string1="ER_Rep1"
declare -- string2="ER_Rep2"
```

`diff  <(echo "$string1" ) <(echo "$string2")`
which returns

```sh
1c1 
< ER_Rep1 
--- 
> ER_Rep2
```

What I am trying to extract is Rep1,Rep2.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several tools like diff, sed, perl, awk etc. without an elegant solution.

Comment: For e.g. If I try `diff` like this for two strings

`diff  <(echo "$string1" ) <(echo "$string2")
1c1
< DT_Rep1
---
> DT_Rep2`

What I am trying to extract is `Rep1,Rep2`

Comment: are the filenames encapsulated into a single string with a comma as delimiter (as displayed)? are the filenames distinct (eg, output from `find` command)? are filenames stored in different variables (or perhaps an array)?

Comment: @abubhava, yes, I will update the question. If you notice the second example has `User1` in all 3 strings. I only need the difference which is `1,2,3` after ``55C_`.

Comment: @markp-fuso, the strings can come from a find command as well. For e.g.

`find . -name "*.ont.bam"`

Comment: If `Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt` becomes `Rep1` but `Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_1_User1.png` becomes just `1` then it's not at all clear what the transformation algorithm is. Please [edit] your question to state it.

Comment: @edmorton, sorry it is not clear. The incoming set of strings can change in pattern and does not conform to a fixed pattern.  That is why I have give two examples and needed a dynamic solution. All I am trying to get is the `difference` between input strings.

Comment: @EdMorton, I added illustrations to make it clearer. Perhaps a better title would have been unique substrings from a list of strings.

Comment: Actually [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274814/dynamically-extract-pattern-unique-to-each-string-in-a-list-of-strings-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment120672745_68274814) is what clarified your requirements, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider this `awk` solution:

```sh
declare -- string1="ER_Rep1"
declare -- string2="ER_Rep2"

awk -F '[_.]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) ++fq[$i]}
END {for (w in fq) if (fq[w] == 1) print w}' <(echo "$string1" ) <(echo "$string2")

Rep1
Rep2
```

This `awk` solution uses `_` or `.` as field separator and stores each field in an associative array `fq` with the value as a number that represents frequency of occurrence of that word.

In the `END` block we iterate each word in `fq` array and print the word if frequency is equal to `1` indicating unique occurrence of that word.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU `awk` in combination with `sort` & `uniq`

```sh
echo 'Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep2.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep3.txt' | awk -v RS='[_.,]' '1' | sort | uniq -u
```

or

`tr` in combination with `sort` & `uniq`

```
echo 'Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep2.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep3.txt' | tr '_.,' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

produces output

```
Rep1
Rep2
Rep3
```

Comment: Very clever solution.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-chara RS. A POSIX awk would treat `RS=[_.,]` as if you just wrote `RS='['`. It'll also output an undesirable extra blank line - you should make it `awk -v RS='[_.,]' 'RT'`

Comment: @glennjackman and @BarathVutukuri, yes indeed  a very nifty solution. I ended up using the `tr` solution :) .

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better way to code this, but what I've done here is a general solution for an arbitrary number of input strings.

- find the longest common prefix of underscore-separated substrings

  ```sh
  longestCommonPrefix() {
      local i prefix file found
      local -a pieces
      IFS=_ read -ra pieces <<<"$1"
      for ((i = ${#pieces[@]} - 1; i > 0; i--)); do
          prefix=$(IFS=_; echo "${pieces[*]:0:i}_")
          found=true
          for file in "${@:2}"; do
              if [[ $file != "$prefix"* ]]; then
                  found=false
                  break
              fi
          done
          if $found; then
              echo "$prefix"
              return
          fi
      done
  }
  ```
- find the longest common suffix (of plain characters)

  ```sh
  longestCommonSuffix() {
      local i suffix file found
      for ((i = ${#1}; i > 0; i--)); do
          suffix=${1: -i}
          found=true
          for file in "${@:2}"; do
              if [[ $file != *"$suffix" ]]; then
                  found=false
                  break
              fi
          done
          if $found; then
              echo "$suffix"
              return
          fi
      done
  }
  ```
- and put them together

  ```sh
  uniqueStrings() {
      local prefix=$(longestCommonPrefix "$@")
      set -- "${@/#"$prefix"/}"
      local suffix=$(longestCommonSuffix "$@")
      printf '%s\n' "${@/%"$suffix"/}"
  }
  ```

Then

```sh
$ uniqueStrings Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt Exp1_ML_Rep2.txt Exp1_ML_Rep3.txt
Rep1
Rep2
Rep3
```

and

```sh
$ uniqueStrings Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_1_User1.png Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_2_User1.png Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_3_User1.png
1
2
3
```

A couple of other examples:

```sh
# nothing in common, should return the input strings
$ uniqueStrings foo bar baz
foo
bar
baz

$ uniqueStrings x_foo13 x_bar13 x_baz13 x_qux13
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

Works with bash v3.2+

Comment: this seems to get closer to what OP has demonstrated; I was also looking at the 'remove the common prefix/suffix' solution, too ... but was thinking of doing it at the individual character level (ie, no delimiters) ... and probably in `awk` (for performance reasons)

Comment: I'd encourage you to submit a solution, I'm curious to see how you'd do it.

Comment: done; a bit verbose but, heh, it's a first pass ...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a solution similar to the one proposed by @glennjackman:

- find the common prefix
- find the common suffix
- strip off the common prefix/suffix and what's left is the difference

Assumptions:

- list of filenames is provided as a comma-delimited string
- variable number of filenames
- do character-by-character comparisons
- no delimiters
- assumes a single 'difference' made up of contiguous characters, eg, when comparing `aBcDe` and `aXcYe` we do not consider `c` to be common, so the difference will be reported as `BcD` and `XcY`

One idea using `awk`, which should have some performance improvement over `bash`-level looping:

```
awk '

# function to return an absolute value of a number

function abs(v) { return v < 0 ? -v : v }

# function to determine if each string has the same character at a given offset;
# return 0 if "no", return 1 if "yes"

function equal() {

    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        pos = offset <= 0 ? length(fname[i]) + offset : offset
        x   = substr(fname[i],pos,1)
        if ( i == 1 )    curr = x
        if ( x != curr ) return 0
    }
    return 1
}

# for now assume strings input using a here-string, and strings are delimited by a comma

FNR==1 { n=split($0,fname,",")
         exit                              # skip to END processing
       }

END {
    # twice through the outer "for" loop:
    #    op =  1 => prefix processing
    #    op = -1 => suffix processing
    # "op" will be used to increment/decrement our offset pointer to
    # perform the character-by-character comparison

    for ( op=1; op>=-1; op=op-2 ) {
        offset = op == 1 ? 1 : 0           # determine initial offset based on op (prefix vs suffix)

        # if all strings have the same character @ a given offset then update our pfx/sfx pointers

        while ( equal() && abs(offset) <= length(fname[1]) ) {
            if ( op == 1 ) pfx = offset
            else           sfx = offset

            offset = offset + op           # go to next offset
        }
    }

if ( pfx == "" ) pfx=0                     # if no common prefix, default to 0
if ( sfx == "" ) sfx=1                     # if no common suffix, default to 1

# use substr() and our pfx/sfx offsets to display the difference

for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ )
    print substr(fname[i], pfx+1, length(fname[i]) - pfx - 1 + sfx )

}' <<< "${in}"
```

**NOTES:**

- a bit verbose at this point; may be able to streamline a bit ...
- code could be modified to work directly with a 'normal' list of files (eg, pipe output from `find` into `awk`); one idea would be to process just the first record (`FNR==1`) and stuff `FILENAME` into the array

Test results:

```
# in='Exp1_ML_Rep1.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep2.txt,Exp1_ML_Rep3.txt'
1
2
3

# in='Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_1_User1.png,Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_2_User1.png,Exp2_DT_10ng_55C_3_User1.png'
1
2
3

# in='x_foo13,x_bar13,x_baz13,x_qux13'
foo
bar
baz
qux

# in='x_foo13,x_bar13,x_baz13,x_abcde23'
foo1
bar1
baz1
abcde2

# in='abcde.123,abcde.123,abcde.123'    # identical
                  # three
                  # blank
                  # lines

# in='abc,def,123456,xyz$$'             # nothing in common
abc
def
123456
xyz$$
```

Comment: The "problem" is that the OP wants "Rep1,Rep2,Rep3" for the first input.